# how to list specific data entrie values greater than the average

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Hi i have to show the noetud and the note_final that are greater than the average note_final for nocours 420111TT during lasession A2019. How would I write down this query in mysql? thank you for the help I'm learning all this stuff for school and find it fun but challenging and this really has me stumped for now.

| nocours | noetud | lasession | date_inscrite | note_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 320112TT | ALCE7888 | H2019 | 2019-01-06 | 90 |
| 320112TT | GAPM9076 | H2019 | 2019-01-06 | 65 |
| 320112TT | HEPP8945 | H2019 | 2019-01-06 | 87 |
| 320112TT | PATE8756 | H2019 | 2019-01-06 | 70 |
| 420111TT | ALCE7888 | A2019 | 2019-09-08 | 78 |
| 420111TT | GAPM9076 | A2019 | 2019-09-08 | 75 |
| 420111TT | HILA7890 | A2019 | 2019-09-08 | 77 |
| 420111TT | PATE8756 | A2019 | 2019-09-08 | 83 |
| 444678TT | ALCE7888 | E2019 | 2019-06-21 | 85 |
| 444678TT | HILA7890 | E2019 | 2019-06-21 | 80 |
| 444678TT | PATE8756 | E2019 | 2019-06-21 | 90 |

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I want the noetud (translates to student number) and their note_final (final grade) for eveery noetud that has a note_final greater than the average note_final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want all rows for the given `(nocrous, lasession)` that are above the average

One option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, avg(note_final) over() avg_note_final
    from mytable t
    where nocrous = '420111TT' and lasession = 'A2019'
) t
where note_final > avg_note_final
```

In versions 5.x of MSQL, you can use a subquery instead:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where nocrous = '420111TT' and lasession = 'A2019' and note_final > (
    select avg(t1.note_final) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.nocrous = t.nocrous and t1.lasession = t.lasession
)
```

Comment: thanks alot for the answer this is easy to understand and read as well for future references! thank you so much!!